# tail recursion Fibonacci in Ruby - Unit Test Error

Tags: ruby

I have here problem with my tail recursion Fibonacci in Ruby.

When I run my code i have got always this error. Where did i do wrong?

```
  1) Error:
test_fibo_rek(Test_fibo_rek):
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 3)
    /Test_Fibonacci.rb:14:in `test_fibo_rek'

1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

---

```
def fibo(n)
  check_pre(
  nat?(n))
  fibo_rek(n,0,1)
end

def fibo_rek(n,fibo1,fibo2)
  if n == 0
    return fibo1
  else
    fibo_rek(n-1,fibo2,fibo1 + fibo2)
  end
end
```

---

```
class Test_fibo_rek < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_fibo_rek

    assert_equal(0,fibo_rek(0))
    assert_equal(13,fibo_rek(7))


    assert_raise(RuntimeError) {fibo_rek('10')}
    assert_raise(RuntimeError) {fibo_rek(-5)}
  end
end
```

Comment: Please fix the code formatting in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your assertions you're calling `fib_rek(0)` etc. even though `fib_rek` takes 3 arguments, not 1.

You meant to call `fib(0)` - fib is the one that only takes one argument.

Comment: Thanks alot. I think my def fibo_rek(n,fibo1,fibo2) method is still wrong. Isn't?

Comment: @KoKo: Note however that ruby doesn't optimize tail recursion unless you specifically enable it as a compile flag (and only in 1.9).